# Sql Server Backup to URL (Azure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, database-backups

I'm trying to take advantage of the new backup to url function in SQL Server.  I have created a valid cert and tried a simple backup, but I get the same error every time no matter what I try.
I have also tried creating a new managed backup.  With the managed backup I see a new storage container but get no new blobs.  When I look through the logs it is getting the same error.

example:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [mydb] 
TO  URL = 'https://mybackups.blob.core.windows.net/sqltest-mssqlserver/backup_2014_08_08.bak' 
WITH  
CREDENTIAL = N'AzureCreds' , 
STATS = 1
GO
```

Message:

```
Msg 3293, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
An error occurred while Backup/Restore to URL was initializing. Error message: Internal engine error, invalid parameters caused fatal error.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: You might find more help on dba.stackexchange.com as this looks more like a DBA than a programmer issue :-)

Comment: Try using Fiddler to capture the HTTP requests that SQL Server issues to Azure. The responses might contain an error and a clue to resolve the problem.; Use trace flag 3051 to turn on verbose logging. Does the event log show something useful?

Comment: What version of SQL and Management Studio? 2012, 2014, SSMS Express?

If you haven't already, read the following MSDN resources: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn435916.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919149

If you are still having issues try isolating the problem to a specific area by executing the backup using PowerShell (as an example) to validate "blob storage" is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use of [Redgate backup pro](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/). by this software you can copy your backup in other location (mirror), network, Host storage. You can use URL in network location or mirror location.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This may or may not be helpful to you, but here is a script I used to backup to URL and restore from URL to a new database.

```
create credential MyStorage 
with identity='mystorage',
secret = 'secretkey';
GO

backup database mydb1
to URL='https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/test1/mydb1.bak'
with credential = 'MyStorage';
GO

restore database mydb2
from URL='https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/test1/mydb1.bak'
with credential = 'MyStorage',
move 'mydb1' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLENT2014\MSSQL\DATA\mydb2.mdf',
move 'mydb1_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLENT2014\MSSQL\DATA\mydb2_log.ldf';
GO
```